# What is the motivation behind the definition of infinitesimal probability $p(x)dx$'s definition?

Tags: probability, symmetry, infinitesimals

I have had this question for a very long time now, which is:-

"Why do we have $p(x)\,dx$ to be defined as the probability of $x$ lying in the interval $[x, x +dx]$ and not the interval $[x - \frac{dx}{2}, x + \frac{dx}{2}]$?"

Why is the preferred direction of evaluation an increase from the given value? Why is it not symmetric about $x$? Is it because of how Riemann sums are evaluated?

Comment: These are equivalent as "motivations", in that the way an integral is the limit of Riemann sums gives flexibility in partitioning the interval of integration.  You might compare the Midpoint Rule and a rule that always evaluates the left-hand endpoint.  That could suggest the centered intervals you ask about are a more natural approach.  But passing to a limit gets us to the same place.

Comment: One conceptual point is that in a definite integral you may not want to go outside the interval of integration.  You can easily work round this, but why do so if it is not necessary?

Comment: @VatsalGarg It's simpler and you get the same answer. (Actually, do you always get the same answer? Analysis loves its pathological counterexamples.)

Comment: @hardmath I agree that they will take you to the same place, but if it indeed is more natural then why is it not as popular?

Comment: @Henry This was a point brought up by my peers as well, but what I am trying to get at is the intuition. And yes we will run into some issues when dealing with endpoints of definite integrals, so what about indefinite integrals then?

Comment: @eyeballfrog So if both the limits do not take you to the same place (probabilistically; because I have no issues as such in Analysis), then how do we judge which one is the true limit?